# C: pthread segfaults

Tags: c, pthreads

I am writing my first C program using pthread. I want to run my function `sha1sum` for all (non-option) arguments provided on the commadline (argv).

```
pthread_t t[256];

c = 0;
for (n = optind; n < argc; n++) {
    if(pthread_create(&t[c], NULL, sha1sum, argv[n])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }
    c++;
}

c = 0;
for (n = optind; n < argc; n++) {
    pthread_join(t[c]);
    c++;
}
```

When run my program with 2 commandline arguments (`file1`, `file2`). it segfaults, sometimes right away, sometimes at the end after having successfully executed the sha1sum function.

Can somebody please point out what is wrong?

## EDIT

Turns out, the program is still sometimes segfaulting. Sometimes right away, sometimes in the middle, sometimes never:

I am posting the whole MCV example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>    

static unsigned char flag = 0;


int sha1sum(char *filename) {

    FILE *f;
    size_t len;
    unsigned char buffer[BUFSIZ]; 

    EVP_MD_CTX hashctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    const EVP_MD *hashptr = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA1");

        f = fopen(filename, "r");

        EVP_MD_CTX_init(&hashctx);
        EVP_DigestInit_ex(&hashctx, hashptr, NULL);

        do {
                len = fread(buffer, 1, BUFSIZ, f);
                EVP_DigestUpdate(&hashctx, buffer, len);
        } while (len == BUFSIZ);

        unsigned int outlen;
        EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&hashctx, buffer, &outlen);
        EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&hashctx);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < outlen; i++)
                printf("%02x", buffer[i]);

        printf("\n");
        fclose(f);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int c,n;
    pthread_t t[256];

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "c")) != EOF) switch(c) {
        case 'c':
            flag |= 1;
            break;
    }

    c = 0;
    for (n = optind; n < argc; n++) {

        if (pthread_create(&t[c], NULL, &sha1sum, argv[n])) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;
        }
        c++;
    }

    c = 0;
    for (n = optind; n < argc; n++) {
        pthread_join(t[c], NULL);
        c++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## EDIT 2

after adding `#include <pthread.h>`, I now get following errors/warnings when compiling:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:67:9: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from test.c:9:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(char *)’
```

Comment: Does it show the same behaviour when running single threaded?

Comment: Also please provide a [MCV example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This snippet looks ok, except that `pthread_join` takes 2 arguments (a minimal `sha1sum` function might be needed to know a bit more).

Comment: @alk - it does not segfault, when I run it only with one argument (one file).

Comment: You should probably have an `#include <pthread.h>` line in your code.

Comment: @Hasturkun - I have included `pthread.h`, but that did not solve the problem

Comment: @MartinVegter: I actually suggested it expecting that warning (since by seeing that you managed to call functions with the wrong number of arguments suggested it was being implicity declared, and most likely not as you'd expect). You should fix your types, will probably go a long way to fixing your issues.

Comment: @Hasturkun - could you please suggest how to fix the types in my example code?

Comment: The compiler is telling you what's wrong, the type for your thread function should be `void* sha1sum(void *arg)` (which you can cast to the correct type). I'd also suggest that you move some of OpenSSL's initialization (ie. `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms` and `ERR_load_crypto_strings`) out of the thread function, as they're might not be reentrant and might behave badly if called from multiple threads in parallel. (alternately, use `pthread_once` from the threads to handle these)

Comment: @Hasturkun - thanks a lot, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some small changes to your code. Now it doesn't crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <getopt.h>

void *sha1sum(void) {
    char *a = malloc(10);
    strcpy(a, "hello world\n");
    pthread_exit((void *) a);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pthread_t t[256];
    int n = 0;
    int c = 0;
    char *b;
    for (n = optind; n < argc; n++) {
        if (pthread_create(&t[c], NULL, &sha1sum, argv[n])) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;
        }
        c++;
    }
    c = 0;
    for (n = optind; n < argc; n++) {
        pthread_join(t[c], (void **) &b);
        printf("b is %s", b);
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
./a.out foo bar baz bletch
b is hello world
b is hello world
b is hello world
b is hello world
```

Comment: Shouldn't this  `pthread_join(t[c], (void **) &b);` better be `void * pv; pthread_join(t[c], &pv); b = pv;`?

Comment: @Dac Saunders - thanks. The problem seems to be, my function did not have `pthread_exit`

Comment: Calling `pthread_exit()` is not needed it there is nothing to return. @MartinVegter

Comment: Your code's issue it that it passes to few parameters to `pthread_join()`. @MartinVegter

Comment: @alk - I have corrected `pthread_join()`, but it still segfaults. I have edited my question, and added MCV example

Answer (score 3):

Change `pthread_join(t[c])` to `pthread_join(t[c], NULL)`

Comment: it still segfaults, even after correcting `pthread_join`. I have edited my question.